# The Punishment of doing Haram while knowing its Haram?

Tags: halal-haram

What is  the punishment of someone who does something forbidden while knowing that it is forbidden?

Is their punishment greater than someone who does not know that its forbidden?

(for example: a person may drink while standing up while knowing that the prophet(pbuh) forbade us from doing so)

Answer (score 2):

When someone intentionally commit sin knowing its punishment.   That shows it soul/conscience is not in his control. This is the reason the greatest jihad is to fight with our soul. "Indeed the soul (nafs) that overwhelmingly commands a person to do sin.” (12:53). That soul (Nafs al-ammārah) which is sovereign over a human being. It can be controlled by constantly remembering God. And fear of His accountability may keep us distance from Sin. Knowledge is the key which influences and inspire us towards good deeds. May God help us!